# How to convert a DicomImage(Dcmtk) with depth=17 to a Mat(Opencv) object?

Tags: c++, opencv, dicom, bitmask, dcmtk

When using this code I don't get the result that I want (see the picture).

```
DicomImage *image = new DicomImage("/home/000001.dcm");
cv::Mat inputImage(int(image->getHeight()), int(image->getWidth()), CV_16UC1, (uchar*)image->getOutputData(16));
```

Because image has a depth of 17, and if change CV_16UC1 to CV_32xx I get a nonsense image.
Obviously a 17bits need more than 16bits to get stored correctly.
My question is, which Opencv Map type should I use (CV_32SC1，CV_32SC2，CV_32SC3，CV_32SC4 or else), what is the difference between them, do I have to use a bitmask to prevent getting garbage in the rest upper bits and how can I do that?

[[image: Pictue]]

Comment: CV_32SC1 should work for monochrome... CV_32SC3 for colored ones. By the documentation I think you have to use, `(uchar*)image->getOutputData(17)` or if you use a colored one or want another frame `(uchar*)image->getOutputData(17, frameNumber, 0) `. The 17 is the depth, it will be padded to 8, 16,32 and so on... so this will be padded to 32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the rendered image is not 16 vs. 17 bit depth (since you've specified to always get 16 bit) but that you haven't selected an appropriate VOI window, e.g. by calling `image->setMinMaxWindow()` before `image->getOutputData()`.